# How to give permission to everyone to copy file from my home directory on server?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I created a folder and a tar file and want to give access (to everyone) to copy that file/folder in their home directory.
I don't have root permission on that server as it is institute owned. Right now I am the owner of the file/folder.

When I try `chmod nobody File.tar.gz` then it gives error: `chown: changing ownership of File.tar.gz: Operation not permitted`

What should be done to grant the permission?

Comment: If you `chmod 604 File.tar.gz` the file will be readable by others and read-writable by you. Since you are the owner, you can do this without root permissions. Btw, the question is off-topic on SO. Ask such things on http://superuser.com

Comment: you can't chown as you are not root, but also you will need to be cognizant   of what perms on your homedir as well, since the will affect who can see that file (ie your homedir is 700, then no matter what you make the files perms, no one will be able to see it)